# I'm trying to install these packages to my Ubuntu Server ( OpenLiteSpeed )

Tags: webserver, openlitespeed

I'm trying to install these packages but I can't install some packages.

```
sudo apt-get install lsphp70 lsphp70-common lsphp70-dev lsphp70-dbg lsphp70-mbstring lsphp70-gettext lsphp70-zip lsphp70-curl lsphp70-mysql lsphp70-mcrypt lsphp70-gd lsphp70-cgi lsphp70-soap lsphp70-sqlite3 lsphp70-xml lsphp70-redis lsphp70-bcmath lsphp70-imagick lsphp70-intl -y
sudo apt-get install lsphp71 lsphp71-common lsphp71-dev lsphp71-dbg lsphp71-mbstring lsphp71-gettext lsphp71-zip lsphp71-curl lsphp71-mysql lsphp71-gd lsphp71-cgi lsphp71-soap lsphp71-sqlite3 lsphp71-xml lsphp71-redis lsphp71-bcmath lsphp71-imagick lsphp71-intl -y
sudo apt-get install lsphp72 lsphp72-common lsphp72-dev lsphp72-dbg lsphp72-mbstring lsphp72-gettext lsphp72-zip lsphp72-curl lsphp72-mysql lsphp72-gd lsphp72-cgi lsphp72-soap lsphp72-sqlite3 lsphp72-xml lsphp72-redis lsphp72-bcmath lsphp72-imagick lsphp72-intl -y
sudo apt-get install lsphp73 lsphp73-common lsphp73-dev lsphp73-dbg lsphp73-mbstring lsphp73-gettext lsphp73-zip lsphp73-curl lsphp73-mysql lsphp73-gd lsphp73-cgi lsphp73-soap lsphp73-sqlite3 lsphp73-xml lsphp73-redis lsphp73-bcmath lsphp73-imagick lsphp73-intl -y
sudo apt-get install lsphp74 lsphp74-common lsphp74-dev lsphp74-dbg lsphp74-mbstring lsphp74-gettext lsphp74-zip lsphp74-curl lsphp74-mysql lsphp74-gd lsphp74-cgi lsphp74-soap lsphp74-sqlite3 lsphp74-xml lsphp74-redis lsphp74-bcmath lsphp74-imagick lsphp74-intl -y
sudo apt-get install lsphp80 lsphp80-common lsphp80-dev lsphp80-dbg lsphp80-mbstring lsphp80-gettext lsphp80-zip lsphp80-curl lsphp80-mysql lsphp80-gd lsphp80-cgi lsphp80-soap lsphp80-sqlite3 lsphp80-xml lsphp80-redis lsphp80-bcmath lsphp80-imagick lsphp80-intl -y
```

E: Unable to locate package lsphp70-mbstring
E: Unable to locate package lsphp70-gettext
E: Unable to locate package lsphp70-zip
E: Unable to locate package lsphp70-mcrypt
E: Package 'lsphp70-gd' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package lsphp70-cgi
E: Unable to locate package lsphp70-soap
E: Unable to locate package lsphp70-xml
E: Unable to locate package lsphp70-bcmath

E: Unable to locate package lsphp71-mbstring
E: Unable to locate package lsphp71-gettext
E: Unable to locate package lsphp71-zip
E: Package 'lsphp71-gd' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package lsphp71-cgi
E: Unable to locate package lsphp71-soap
E: Unable to locate package lsphp71-xml
E: Unable to locate package lsphp71-bcmath

E: Unable to locate package lsphp72-mbstring
E: Unable to locate package lsphp72-gettext
E: Unable to locate package lsphp72-zip
E: Package 'lsphp72-gd' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package lsphp72-cgi
E: Unable to locate package lsphp72-soap
E: Unable to locate package lsphp72-xml
E: Unable to locate package lsphp72-bcmath

E: Unable to locate package lsphp73-mbstring
E: Unable to locate package lsphp73-gettext
E: Unable to locate package lsphp73-zip
E: Package 'lsphp73-gd' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package lsphp73-cgi
E: Unable to locate package lsphp73-soap
E: Unable to locate package lsphp73-xml
E: Unable to locate package lsphp73-bcmath
E: Unable to locate package php73-intl

E: Unable to locate package lsphp74-mbstring
E: Unable to locate package lsphp74-gettext
E: Unable to locate package lsphp74-zip
E: Package 'lsphp74-gd' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package lsphp74-cgi
E: Unable to locate package lsphp74-soap
E: Unable to locate package lsphp74-xml
E: Unable to locate package lsphp74-bcmath

E: Unable to locate package lsphp80-mbstring
E: Unable to locate package lsphp80-gettext
E: Unable to locate package lsphp80-zip
E: Package 'lsphp80-gd' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package lsphp80-cgi
E: Unable to locate package lsphp80-soap
E: Unable to locate package lsphp80-xml
E: Unable to locate package lsphp80-redis
E: Unable to locate package lsphp80-bcmath
E: Unable to locate package php80-intl

Please help me.

Comment: Some packages have already been combined into the common package. Since you want to install many packages, maybe you can try, e.g. "apt-get install lsphp74-*" -y to install all lsphp74 packages.